# Javascript - Seperate all IPs on page and use them as strings

Tags: javascript, string, ip, string-matching

I'm trying to grab all IPs on a specific page and run a function on each of them; however I can only find (through research) how to grab all IP's on the page as a single string. Not very proficient in JS, as you may be able to tell.

Grab as single string:

```
var markup = document.getElementsByClassName('border_wrapper')[0].innerHTML;
alert(markup.match(/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/g).join("\n"))
```

I'm assuming I'll need a for loop to run them in a function. resolve(newstring);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.join` makes a string, remove it;

```
var markup = document.getElementsByClassName('border_wrapper')[0].innerHTML;

var list = markup.match(/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/g);

if (list != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        alert(list[i]);
}
```

Using a cache to prevent repeats;

```
var markup = document.getElementsByClassName('border_wrapper')[0].innerHTML;

var list = markup.match(/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/g);

if (list != null) {
    var processed = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (!processed[list[i]])
        {
            processed[list[i]] = true;
            alert(list[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. As a separate question - is there away for me to prevent an IP from repeating itself?